# constraint extrema problem (Lagrange function)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I do not understand one thing in solving constraints extrema problem using Lagrange function. Let us have a function $f(x)$ and a constraint $g(x)=0$ I saw in textbooks solutions using a Lagrange function with a real lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ in the form $$ L(x)=f(x)+\lambda g(x)$$ or $$ L(x)=f(x)-\lambda g(x)$$ How we know which sign to use when?

Comment: The sign on $\lambda$ is entirely arbitrary, both work equally well.

Comment: Thanks, I was very confused  with using different signs.

Comment: Let $\lambda^*$ the optimal solution for $\lambda$ in the first case. Then in the second case $-\lambda^*$ is the optimal solution for $\lambda$. And then $-(-\lambda^*)=\lambda^*$. If the optimal solution in the first case is positive/negative the optimal solution in the second case is negative/positive. The result is the same.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now.